# External memory is not enabled in mingw' on XGboost

Tags: c++, c, xgboost

I'm trying to run xgboost and am getting an error trying to convert the libsvm file type into an xgbmatrix.

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('train#dtrain.cache')
XGBoostError: b'[16:45:24] src/data/data.cc:248: External memory is not enabled in mingw'
```

It seems to be caused by

```
void DMatrix::SaveToLocalFile(const std::string& fname) {
  data::SimpleCSRSource source;
  source.CopyFrom(this);
  std::unique_ptr<dmlc::Stream> fo(dmlc::Stream::Create(fname.c_str(), "w"));
  source.SaveBinary(fo.get());
}

DMatrix* DMatrix::Create(std::unique_ptr<DataSource>&& source,
                         const std::string& cache_prefix) {
  if (cache_prefix.length() == 0) {
    return new data::SimpleDMatrix(std::move(source));
  } else {
#if DMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD
    return new data::SparsePageDMatrix(std::move(source), cache_prefix);
#else
    LOG(FATAL) << "External memory is not enabled in mingw";
    return nullptr;
#endif
  }
}
```

On this github file: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/data/data.cc

I'm not familiar with C so I am having trouble debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is that you're using the URL based `DMatrix` creation. i.e. you gave the data file as  `'train#dtrain.cache'`.

The cache can be created only if your compiler has external memory support. mingw does not have that sadly. Hence, just give your file as `"train"` and ensure it's libsvm format and all should be fine.

Comment: Does it is still keep using external memory this way? I'm having trouble understanding how to use the external memory version..

Comment: This answer was for xgboost 0.6 - I am not sure about the 0.8 version currently as I have not started using it yet.